# c# KeyEventArgs with lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

Is this possible to write with lambda expression?

I tried private void CancelBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => Close(); and it works.

```
private void UpdateEmployees_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a lambda expression by passing an input parameters to handle `OnKeyDown` event, without declaring `UpdateEmployees_KeyDown` method

```cs
UpdateEmployees.OnKeyDown += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

Your first expression `private void CancelBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => Close();` isn't a lambda expression, it's an [expression-bodied method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#methods), which is available starting from C# 6